# How can i change workflow persistence values?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, state-machine-workflow

I am developing an application using state machine workflow in .Net.

My workflow persisted some values based on the table contents.
The persisted values should be changed when the table contents are changed.
But it is not happening
How can I do that?

Regards
Dhanraj.S

Comment: What workflow is that? Could you please state the language/technology and add appropriate tags?

Comment: Language C#.Net. StateMachine Workflow in Windows Workflow Foundation Technology.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you mean

1. You called workflow with some data and then persisted the workflow instance
2. Now those values (in database other than wf persistance db (if you are using sql server for wf persistance)) are changed and
3. you want the workflow to do stuff or persist according to the changed values.

You need to reload the persisted workflow and run it for the changed values.